# How can I download a small section of a long Youtube video?

Tags: video, download, youtube

I need to download about 30 seconds from the end of 50 different 30-minute long videos. Is there any way to do this without downloading the whole of each video?

Comment: http://techsalsa.com/split-chop-or-cut-youtube-videos-directly-before-downloading/

Comment: That's perfect! Is there any way I can download the created video as opposed to just view it?

Comment: Is the 30s section the beginning or can it be any part of the video?

Comment: @Karan It's always at the end